# как запустить python скрипт с данными текстового файла, созданного Android приложенем, написанного на kotlin

Tags: python, kotlin

у меня есть приложение и, допустим, парсер на python

пользователь вводит, например, название книги. приложение сохраняет название в текстовый файл input.txt

Как запустить python скрипт, чтобы она сразу начал обрабатывать этот текстовый файл, а результат записал в result.txt, и приложение сразу же отобразило этот результат пользователю?

Если вы знаете, как можно прийти к этому результату проще, буду рад узнать об этом(можно просто дать ссылку на статью(англ или русский языки))
но по возможности хотелось бы избежать использования БД или лок.серверов

Comment: передавать данные через файлы - костыль. можете апи на питоне написать

Comment: А что там на питоне такого, что нельзя внедрить а Андроид-приложение и избежать этого обмена файлами?